Cannot choose object to conform to 'text on curve' with text object

This is an example of the scence that I have. I want the text to conform around the shape of the circle. However, the eyedropper tool will not select the circle. Likewise, when the curve modifier is applied to the text, the eyedropper tool will not select the circle as a reference. There simply isn't any option for me to choose from, it says no other objects are in the scene.
Is this a problem of aligning the objects in the same plane? How do i trouble shoot this?

You need a curve object, you have a mesh one

thanks duarte, that's the solution. i don't know how to upvote/pin your comment, but it works.
